# When loading swf file blank screen appears

Tags: android, flash

I used the following code to load swf file , but it shows a blank screen.

In manifest I have mentioned  `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"`

My code is as follows :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    mWebView.setFocusable(true);
    mWebView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    //mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
    mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);

    Log.d(TAG, "before loading url");
    mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/carspeakers.swf");

    Log.d(TAG, "after loading url");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

Add the below line and try..

```
mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
```

Hope this will help..

Comment: '<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

</LinearLayout>'

Comment: <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.testing2.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>